# C# - how to get path to directory where Program.cs is on Windows from Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I used .NET Core SDK (v 2.1.301) to create a solution, create a console project, and add the project to the solution on Windows.

```
dotnet new sln -o ConsoleSol
dotnet new console -o ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp
dotnet sln ConsoleSol/ConsoleSol.sln add ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp/ConsoleApp.csproj
```

The folder structure looks like:

```
ConsoleSol/
├── ConsoleApp
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── Debug
│   │       └── netcoreapp2.1
│   ├── ConsoleApp.csproj
│   ├── obj
│   │   ├── Debug
│   │   │   └── netcoreapp2.1
│   │   └── project.assets.json
│   └── Program.cs
└── ConsoleSol.sln
```

I want to get the path to `ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp` without hard-coding the path.
The reason I want to do this is so that I can create a file on that directory.

How can I get the path to `ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp` (i.e., path where ConsoleApp.csproj and Progam.cs exists) from Program.cs?

I tried the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        Console.WriteLine(directory);
    }
}
```

But `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the path to `ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1`

**NOTE:** I am not trying to get the path to the .exe, which can be obtained by calling `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`. I am instead trying to get the path to `Program.cs`

Comment: You want to get the location to the source files of an executable program from the actual executable program as it's executing? Is that correct?

Comment: Looks like you need this: http://codebuckets.com/2017/10/19/getting-the-root-directory-path-for-net-core-applications/

Comment: This still feels like 
an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to explain the actual goal and why. Because it looks like you are mixing concerns. `Program.cs` does not exist to the compiled code.

Comment: Are you working on a VS extension or nuget package or is this meant to be something for run-time?

Comment: @STLDeveloper - I want to get the path where Program.cs exists, not where the dll exists (bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1)

Comment: @Nkosi - I am not trying to solve a particular problem. Right now I am currently hard-coding the path. I'm wondering if there is something built-into .NET that will allow me to get the path to where Program.cs exists (something like `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. I'm starting to think that this isn't something built-in. I guess I need to implement something like this on my own?

Comment: While you can clearly get the path to the executing assembly, I don't believe you'll be able to get the absolute path of the original source code.  If my recollection is correct, the paths to all source modules in a Visual Studio project are stored relative to the path of the project file itself.  That said, you may be able to do something during the build step that would store the absolute path of the project, and from that you may be able to extrapolate the path to a given source file with in it.

Comment: @Tudor your comment seems to suggest that there isn't anything built-into .NET (such as `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`) that would allow me to programmatically get the path to where Program.cs is from within Program.cs. It seems like people are implementing their own methods to get the app root directory.

Comment: @kimbaudi, regarding your comment to Tudor, just because you can get the path to an executing assembly, what makes you believe you can go from that to getting the paths of its source files?  The executable could have been moved to any location on disk.

Comment: @STLDeveloper so far Tudor's comments is the only comment that attempts to get the application root path (albeit in a questionable way by using regex to split the path).

Comment: @kimbaudi - As the article points out, it's going to give you paths relative to the path of the executable.  Since the executable can be moved or copied anywhere on the machine, there is absolutely nothing that restricts the paths of source modules to have any relationship whatsoever with the path of the executable. This question is nonsensical.

Comment: @STLDeveloper I'm starting to understand that its not possible/practical to get the path to location of source files from the path of the executable. I shouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @kimbaudi - There is certainly no harm in asking!  How else can we learn?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that one can only get the path to the .NET executing assembly, and the assembly can be stored any where on disk, it is impossible to get the path to any source file of the assembly.  Unless, of course, you are executing from the /bin path that is created in the project.

Once the assembly is moved, you have no hope of using its current path to trace back to the path of the source files used to create that assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Path.GetDirectoryName` twice for current directory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` returns path to `ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1`. I want `ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp`

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx)

Combine that with [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) if all you want is the directory.

Comment: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns the path to `ConsoleSol/ConsoleApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1`. This is not what I want. I've been search google and stackoverflow and everyone simply gives this as the answer.

Comment: @kimbaudi: You know what compiling actually means right? C# isn't a interpreted language like PHP where you can do such things you request

Comment: @Tseng yes i know what compiling means. when i run `dotnet buid` I am compiling `Program.cs` to a dll that is located in `bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1`. I am not trying to get the path to the executable/assembly. I want the path to Program.cs

Comment: @kimbaudi: Obviously you don't know what compiling means. It translates the source code into IL. Generally the information about the source files and their location is lost in that process (it still may exist in debug symbols). That's why you can't get it and why everyone telling you that you try to solve the wrong problem. Did it ever come into your mind to configure the pat in appsettings.json and read it from there when the application starts?

Comment: @Tseng thanks for your comment! Yes, source file location is lost in the compilation process so its unrealistic to try to get path of source code. I should just hard-code the path in some config file instead of trying to get the path some other way. I now realize my miskake. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what the path of the file was at the time it was compiled using the rather new C# feature: "[Caller Information Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)".  Create a function, give it have an optional string parameter (say callerPath) and mark it with the [CallerFilePathAttribute], and presto, you get the compile-time path of file containing the calling function (if you call it *without* specifying a value for that parameter).

For example, create this function:

```
private void GetMeThatCallerPath([CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "") {
    LogThePath(sourceFilePath);
}
```

and then call it from the file whose path you want to log:

```
GetMeThatCallerPath();
```

Presto, your LogThePath function will get called with the compile-time path to the file that contained the `GetMeThatCallerPath` call.

For what it's worth, those attributes can really simplify logging/diagnostic code.

Comment: i appreciate the answer, but this is not what I was looking for. And in retrosepect, I feel it is better to specify the path explicitly. I can see it being used for logging/diagnostics, however.

Comment: @kimbaudi: OK.  I'm at a loss for figuring out what you are looking for.  The only possible knowable location for Progam.cs is where it was at compile time.  In general, you don't deploy source with your application (and, if you did, it's very unlikely that it would be in the same relative location to the EXE as it was at compile time.  If it will be at the same relative location, consider getting the EXE location (in the normal fashion), getting the compile-time source location (as I show), and computing the relative location by hand (..\..\whatever)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot get this at runtime, but in pre- and post events there are several variables you can use, if what you wanna do can be solved before or after compilation.

Two of the variables are:
`$(ProjectDir)` : projectfolder
`$(OutDir)` : something like `"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\"`

You can specify a CMD script in your project file `.csproj` e.g.:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   ...
  <Target Name="PostBuild" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)&quot;"/>
  </Target>
  ...
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is the solution to your problem which works on any OS:

```cs
// using dotnet 6.0.0

var directory = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
var slice = new ArraySegment<string>(directory, 0, directory.Length - 4);
var path = Path.Combine(slice.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine($"Path of Program.cs is: {path}")
```

in Terminal/Powershell:

```sh
dotnet run
# Users/user_name/Projects/Application

dotnet run --project Application
# Users/user_name/Projects/Application

dotnet run --project Projects/Application
# Users/user_name/Projects/Application
```